# Magento 2 Entering Wrong Captcha clearing form data

Tags: magento2, forms, captcha

In Magento 2 If **Captcha is wrong** then after submit all detail of form is **getting empty**.

What approach can be taken to make it independent so that form should **not get empty** ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137325/magento-2-server-side-validation-not-showing-filled-up-data-while-error-solved

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Arunendra  I have just started no code yet am figuring out to make it possible.